# Font-size changes on contenteditable div

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

I have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PavSidhu/1673e4kk/) which shows my issue. When you focus on the contenteditable div, and press the 'list' button, the font will increase. This is because I set `font-size: 2em;` in the div. If I set this to pixels it is fine however I would like to set it to an 'em' value for scaling.

Is there a way to maintain the font size in ems? Thanks.

Comment: So do you not want the font size to increase?

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep the font the same size.

Comment: That happens only in Chrome because instead of just inserting a list, it's wrapping the contents with a styled span, so any style that you apply on the parent is copied to the new element. '<span style="font-size: 2em;">Some Text</span>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the unit from `em` to `rem`

while `em` is relative to the font size of its direct or nearest parent, rem is only relative to the html (root) font-size

See the difference here [Rem Vs Em](https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/)

Comment: but still, what if you want to apply em to content editable ?